# OnTriggerEnter doesn't trigger when hitting another object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{
    if(col.tag == "PowerUp")
    {
        Debug.Log("You've got a ");
    }
```

I've got a ball and a power up and I want the ball to touch the power up and basically activate by colliding, though, it doesn't work.
I have added rigidbody to the player and collision to both the player and the power up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about 2D collision triggers in Unity, a couple of conditions need to be met:

- All objects "colliding" need to have a `Collider2D` component (e.g. a `BoxCollider2D`).
- At least one of the objects "colliding" needs to have a `Rigidbody2D` component.
- At least one of the objects needs to have its `Collider2D` configured to be a trigger.

After that, the `OnTriggerEnter2D()` method will be called on all involved objects that "collide".

---

From what you have described, it appears that you only have to set the `Is Trigger` property to `true` in the Inspector:

[image: "Is Trigger" checked in the Inspector]

Depending on your game design it might be beneficial to configure (only) the Power-Ups as triggers in order to keep a regular collider on your Player; this will allow the player to still physically interact with the environment, while being able to trigger with objects of interest.

---

On a different note, you probably also want to swap out your tag comparison code

```cs
if (col.tag == "PowerUp")
```

with a `CompareTag()` call like so:

```cs
if (col.CompareTag("PowerUp"))
```

The reasons are a bit technical, but the short version is that it's a bit faster, saves you from memory related issues in the long run and you'll get a Unity-specific error in the console if the tag doesn't exist.